# Blessed by your wishes

Tags: grammaticality, email

We are blessed with a baby girl. We got many congratulations, wishes and blessings through mail and SMS.

In my reply, I've mentioned

> The little angel is blessed by your wishes

Is this a right phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine as it is, but you could perhaps make it:

> The little angel is blessed by your *good* wishes.

Comment: And I might make it more personal and say, "***Our*** little angel..."

Comment: I'd change *by* to *with*.